# Dashed Line with marker when adding plot from table

Tags: pgfplots

In the `pgfplot`, I would like to have a line plot from a table which is read from a `.csv` file. I would like to have a line which is dashed and has a marker.

I put the code like this -

`\addplot table[x=N,y=No_Sym][mark=*, red, dashed] {data.dat};`

However this does not work. Can anyone tell me the right way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: The line styles need to be provided to the `\addplot` command, not the `table` keyword, so you would say `\addplot [mark=*, red, dashed] table [x=N,y=No_Sym] {data.dat};`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer should be -

`\addplot [mark=*, red, dashed] table[x=N,y=No_Sym] {data.dat};`